# Active Directory Groups and CruiseControl.NET

Tags: active-directory, cruisecontrol.net, active-directory-group

I'm using CruiseControl.NET 1.6 and I want to restrict forceBuild access to some projects.  I'd like to use existing Active Directory groups to do this rather than enumerating the users in each project and having to manage them in the CC Config files.  Is this possible?  Can anyone point me to an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is useful information in the CC.net documentation on configuring [LDAP User Authentication](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/LDAP_User_Authentication) and [Role (groups of users) Permissions](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Role_Permission). Did you try the following?

```
<ldapUser name="*" domain="somewhere.com" />
```

A more encompassing example is [Scenario 2](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Scenario_2_Large_In-house_Development_Team)